# Does  weak*-separability of $X^*$ imply that $X$ is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does separability follow from weak-* sequential separability of dual space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43365/does-separability-follow-from-weak-sequential-separability-of-dual-space)
>   [$\omega^*$-separability of $l_\infty^*$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41851)

Recently I read a Theorem stating, Let $X$ be a Banach space which is separable then every weakly compact subset is metrizable. I noticed that the separability is used in order to prove that $X^{*}$ is weakly* separable and in the rest of proof separability of $X$ is no longer used.

Motivated by that my question is, let $X$ be a Banach space if $X^*$ is $\mathrm{weakly}^*$ separable then does this imply that $X$ is separable, if not this would weaken the hypothesis.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43365/does-separability-follow-from-weak-sequential-separability-of-dual-space

Comment: This is probably inspired by a proof of the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem, so you might be interested in the references given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/153194) (I recommend having a look at Whitley's paper mentioned in the accepted answer). Seeing that the thread linked to by @Asaf gives a negative answer to a weaker question I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually $(\ell^\infty)^\ast$ is weak$^\ast$-separable, as I argue [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41851), so that's a much more elementary counterexample.

Comment: @t.b. thanks that is much better!Also could this be a good counterexample because of the schur property of  $l_1$ ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind. It's also a good example because $\ell^\infty$ is a [Grothendieck space](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/128388/5363) :)