# Weak closedness in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-topology

It's known that $L^1[0,1]\supset L^2[0,1]\supset L^3[0,1]\supset\cdots\supset L^\infty[0,1]$. How to show without using axiom of choice (nor Hahn-Banach Theorem) to show the unit ball in $L^\infty[0,1]$ is weakly closed in $L^3[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "weak-closedness"?

Comment: I assume it means that the unit ball in $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$ as a subset of $L^3([0, 1])$ is closed in the weak topology on $L^3([0, 1])$.

Comment: Yes. More precisely, any sequence $

Comment: Thanks for your proof (suddenly deleted). I tried to prove it without use of Riesz representation theorm, so the use of Kakutani Theorem is a way.

Comment: Kakutani relies on Banach-Alaoglu, which is equivalent to the axiom of choice. I've undeleted the answer and can leave it, if you'd like.

Comment: I also missed this. By the way, is Banach-Alaoglu Theorem equivalent to AC , or only Tyconoff's theorem, as you wrote below ?

Comment: After doing a bit more reading, I've found that technically, [Banach-Alaoglu is equivalent in ZF to the ultrafilter lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145271/is-banach-alaoglu-equivalent-to-ac), [which is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this for general $L^p([0, 1])$, $1\leq p < \infty$. First, for $f\in L^{\infty}([0, 1])$, $$\|f\|_{L^p([0, 1])}\leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}([0, 1])}$$ as an [application of Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings). Therefore, if $f_n\to f$ in $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^p([0, 1])$, so closed subsets of $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$ are closed as subsets of $L^p([0, 1])$. Furthermore, the closed unit ball in $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$ is a subset of the closed unit ball of $L^p([0, 1])$ by the above inequality. As (1) the closed unit ball of $L^p([0, 1])$ is weakly compact by Kakutani's theorem, (2) [strong closure is equivalent to weak closure for convex subsets of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151148/a-convex-subset-of-a-banach-space-is-closed-if-and-only-if-it-is-weakly-closed), and (3) a [closed subset of a compact set is compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Subspace_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact) in any topology, we have that the closed unit ball of $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$ is weakly compact in $L^p([0, 1])$. This is a stronger implication than the weak closedness of the closed unit ball of $L^{\infty}([0, 1])$ in $L^p([0, 1])$, as $L^p([0, 1])$ is Hausdorff in the weak topology (and therefore weakly compact sets are weakly closed).

Comment: The proof of Alaoglu's theorem that you cite uses Tyconoff's theorem, which is [known to be equivalent to the axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_axiom_of_choice_from_Tychonoff.27s_theorem).

Comment: Ah, true, good catch. I figured this was too easy to work without the AC hiding somewhere behind.

Comment: This is a simple viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f,f_n:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ are a collection of measurable functions such that $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ for all $n$, and such that $\int_0^1 f_ng \stackrel{n \to \infty} {\longrightarrow} \int_0^1 fg$ for every $g \in L^{3/2}[0,1]$ (which means $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^3$). We need to show that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1$.

For positive functions $g \in L^{3/2}$, we clearly have $\int_0^1 fg \leq \int_0^1 g$, since $\int f_ng \leq \int |f_n|g \leq \int g$ for every $n$.

In particular, letting $g=1_A$, we get that $\int_A f \leq m(A)$ for every Borel set $A$ (here $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure).

Now for contradiction, assume $\|f\|_{\infty} > 1$. That means that $m(\{x:f(x)>1)+m(\{x:f(x)<-1\})>0$, so wlog, let's say that $m(\{x:f(x)>1\})>0$. Then letting $A:=\{x:f(x)>1\}$, we find that $\int_Af > \int_A 1=m(A)$, which contradicts the result of the preceding paragraph. Thus we conclude that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: One should realize that this answer only shows the weak **sequential** closedness.

Comment: @gerw Yes, you are right. My mistake. So, is the weak topology not first-countable?

Comment: @gerw Actually, unless I'm mistaken [one may show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914570/regarding-metrizability-of-weak-weak-topology-and-separability-of-banach-spaces) without using AC that the weak topology on $L^3$ is induced by the metric $$d(f,g) = \sum_n 2^{-n} \int_{[0,1]} |(f-g)h_n|$$ where $\{h_n\}$ is a dense subset of $L^{3/2}$. Thus it is first countable, so sequentially closed sets are closed. Let me know if that is incorrect, or if AC is somehow used.

Comment: @Shalop: The weak topology is only metrizable on *bounded* subsets of $L^{3/2}$. However, the unit ball of $L^\infty$ is contained in a bounded subset of $L^{3/2}$, so it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that sounds more correct. Also, it's the weak topology on $L^3$.