# Example of a locally-convex topological vector space which is not metrizable

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

> I seek an example of a locally-convex topological vector space which is not a metric space.

From google I found an example [LF-Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LF-space).
Does there exist other examples ?

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of examples ...
If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, then the dual space $X^*$ equipped with the weak-* topology is a locally-convex space which is not metrisable.

Cf [Regarding metrizability of weak/weak* topology and separability of Banach spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/914570/316749) in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical example is the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).

The easy example is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with seminorm defined as $\|(x,y)\| = |x|$, which is not a metric space but only a [pseudometric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space).

Answer (score 0):

According to $\pi$-base, the set of functions from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ with the topology of pointwise convergence is not metrizable: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000103

It is locally convex by definition: take the seminorms $p_x(f) := |f(x)|$ for all $x$.

I found this example among the answers to this question: [Non-Metrizable Topological Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969257)